# How to use use the gst_app_src_push_buffer() manually with custom event

Tags: qt, c++11, gstreamer

I want to use the gstreamer's appsrc element to send an images to the gstreamer's pipeline as video stream. I look on the appsrc example, where are used the time-based streaming format. Where each buffer has the timestamp steps on 0.5 second, and the 'need-data' callback calls every 0.5 second.

But in my case, I do not need this feature, I need to use the gst_app_src_push_buffer() directly when an image becomes ready to send (as I understand).

I use the following initialization code (simplified, pseudocode):

```
void Foo::initializeGst()
{
    // Init gstreamer.
    ::gst_init(nullptr, nullptr);

    // Configure appsrc element.
    m_appsrc = ::gst_element_factory_make(
                "appsrc", "source");

    ::g_object_set(G_OBJECT(m_appsrc),
                   "stream-type", GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_STREAM,
                   "is-live", true,
                   nullptr);

    // Configure appsrc caps.
    const auto caps = ::gst_caps_new_simple(
                "video/x-raw",
                "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "BGRA",
                "width", G_TYPE_INT, 800,
                "height", G_TYPE_INT, 600,
                "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 0, 1,
                nullptr);

    ::g_object_set(G_OBJECT(m_appsrc),
                   "caps", caps,
                   nullptr);

    // Configure video convertor element.
    const auto conv = ::gst_element_factory_make(
                "videoconvert", "conv");

    // Configure video encoder element.
    const auto videoenc = ::gst_element_factory_make(
                "x264enc", "video_encoder");

    // Configure payloader element.
    const auto payloader = ::gst_element_factory_make(
                "rtph264pay", "payloader");

    ::g_object_set(G_OBJECT(payloader),
                   "config-interval", 60,
                   nullptr);

    // Configure udpsink element.
    const auto udpsink = ::gst_element_factory_make(
                "udpsink", "udpsink");

    ::g_object_set(G_OBJECT(udpsink),
                   "host", "127.0.0.1",
                   "port", 50666,
                   nullptr);

    // Build pipeline.
    m_pipeline = ::gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");

    ::gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(m_pipeline),
                       m_appsrc,
                       conv,
                       videoenc,
                       payloader,
                       udpsink,
                       nullptr);

    const auto result = ::gst_element_link_many(
                m_appsrc, conv, videoenc, payloader, udpsink, nullptr);

    if (!result) {
        qDebug() << "Unable to initialize the GST";
    } else {
        // Play.
        const auto status = ::gst_element_set_state(m_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
        qDebug() << "Status:" << status;
    }
}
```

And the following buffer-access code (simplified, pseudocode):

```
void Foo::setImage(const QImage &image)
{
    GstBuffer *buffer = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc(m_image.byteCount());
    const auto bytesCopied = ::gst_buffer_fill(
                buffer, 0, m_image.constBits(), m_image.byteCount());

    const auto result = ::gst_app_src_push_buffer(
                GST_APP_SRC(m_appsrc), buffer);

    qDebug() << "Push result" << result << "for copied bytes"
             <<  bytesCopied;
}
```

But, nothing happens, I did not see the video stream, e.g. using the VLC player (with the SDP file), and, after some time, the application crashes.

But, if I use the "need-data" signal, and the GST_FORMAT_TIME option:

```
::g_object_set(G_OBJECT(appsrc),
               "stream-type", 0,
               "is-live", TRUE,
               "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME,
               nullptr);

g_signal_connect(appsrc, "need-data", G_CALLBACK(need_data_cb), nullptr);

static void need_data_cb(GstElement *appsrc, guint unused_size, gpointer user_data)
{
    static gboolean white = FALSE;
    static GstClockTime timestamp = 0;

    const guint size = 800 * 600 * 4;
    GstBuffer *buffer = ::gst_buffer_new_allocate(nullptr, size, nullptr);

    // This makes the image black/white.
    ::gst_buffer_memset(buffer, 0, white ? 0xff : 0x0, size);

    white = !white;

    GST_BUFFER_PTS(buffer) = timestamp;
    GST_BUFFER_DURATION(buffer) = ::gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, 20);

    timestamp += GST_BUFFER_DURATION(buffer);

    GstFlowReturn ret;
    ::g_signal_emit_by_name(appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);

    ::gst_buffer_unref(buffer);
}
```

then it works...

I did not understand at all, what I need to change to make it work without the timestamps and the GST_FORMAT_TIME option.

Could someone help me please?

BR,
Denis

Answer (score 9):

Ah.. I'm sorry, I stupid.

It is enougth to setup the GST_FORMAT_TIME:

```
::g_object_set(G_OBJECT(appsrc),
               "stream-type", 0,
               "is-live", TRUE,
               "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME,
               nullptr);
```

And at the buffer creation just set to buffer pts field a current timestamp value, e.g. using the QElapsedTimer:

```
void Foo::setImage(const QImage &image)
{
    GstBuffer *buffer = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc(m_image.byteCount());
    const auto bytesCopied = ::gst_buffer_fill(
                buffer, 0, m_image.constBits(), m_image.byteCount());

    GST_BUFFER_PTS(buffer) = m_timer.nsecsElapsed();

    const auto result = ::gst_app_src_push_buffer(
                GST_APP_SRC(m_appsrc), buffer);

    qDebug() << "Push result" << result << "for copied bytes" 
             << bytesCopied;
}
```

Now, all works, yeehaa.. :)